# How to merge dictionary of dataframes on shared column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge, concatenation

I have a dictionary of 7 dataframes of t-statistic values (for a different clinical site), where each dataframe has two columns of about 100 Brain ROIs and the t statistic value for that ROI. My goal is to create a dataframe of each ROI with each t-statistic values.

For this post though, for the sake of brevity and health information I will use a sample dictionary of dataframes on something a bit different. `ROI = character`, and `t-statistic = color_{}`.

I have tried passing the dictionary values into `pd.concat` with `join="inner"` and I am getting duplicate columns for the shared column I want to merge on.

**Before / Dictionary**

```
In[1]:  sega_df_dict

Out[1]: 
{'generic':   character                         color_generic
 0            Sonic                             Blue
 1            Tails                             Yellow
 2            Knuckles                          Red
 3            Amy                               Pink
 4            Shadow                            Black
 
 [5 rows x 2 columns],

 'precise':   character                         color_precise
 0            Sonic                             Cobalt
 1            Tails                             Gold
 2            Knuckles                          Crimson
 3            Amy                               Rose Gold
 4            Shadow                            Ebony

 [5 rows x 2 columns]
```

**Current After / Result**

```
In[2]:  sega_final_df = pd.concat(sega_df_dict.values(), axis=1, join="inner")

Out[2]:

        character       color_generic       character       color_precise
0       Sonic           Blue                Sonic           Cobalt
1       Tails           Yellow              Tails           Gold
2       Knuckles        Red                 Knuckles        Crimson
3       Amy             Pink                Amy             Rose Gold
4       Shadow          Black               Shadow          Ebony
```

**Desired Result**

```
In[3]: ...

Out[3]:

        character       color_generic       color_precise
0       Sonic           Blue                Cobalt
1       Tails           Yellow              Gold
2       Knuckles        Red                 Crimson
3       Amy             Pink                Rose Gold
4       Shadow          Black               Ebony
```

Do I have to reset my index or join along a specific axis?

Answer (score 1):

You should *merge* on 'character' instead of joining your dfs:

```
sega_final_df = reduce(lambda df1, df2: pd.merge(df1, df2,on=['character'],
                                            how='inner'), sega_df_dict.values())
```